# Use WPF DoubleAnimation multiple times (ReSharper shows error in XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I want to use a DoubleAnimation multiple times. Here the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DoubleAnimation x:Key="LeftAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="0" To="100" />
        <DoubleAnimation x:Key="TopAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0" To="100" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorder1">
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="LeftAnimation" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorder2">
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="LeftAnimation" />
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="TopAnimation" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Canvas>
        <Border x:Name="AnimatedBorder1" Background="Blue" Width="20" Height="20" />
        <Border x:Name="AnimatedBorder2" Background="Red" Width="20" Height="20" />
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

The code works fine, but ReSharper underlines **LeftAnimation** in line `<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="LeftAnimation" />` and says: "*Invalid resource type: expected type is 'TriggerCollection', actual type is 'DoubleAnimation'.*"

Is that really a problem or is this a bug in ReSharper (version 9.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an editted solution:

1. Resources:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
   <TimelineCollection x:Key="TimelinesCollectionKey1">
       <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="0" To="100" />
   </TimelineCollection>
   <TimelineCollection x:Key="TimelinesCollectionKey2">
       <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0" To="100" />
   </TimelineCollection></Window.Resources>
   ```
2. Triggers:

   ```
   <Window.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorder1">
               <!--<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="LeftAnimation" />-->
               <Storyboard.Children>
                   <ParallelTimeline Children="{StaticResource TimelinesCollectionKey1}"></ParallelTimeline>
               </Storyboard.Children>
           </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
       <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorder2">
               <Storyboard.Children>
                   <ParallelTimeline Children="{StaticResource TimelinesCollectionKey1}"></ParallelTimeline>
                   <ParallelTimeline Children="{StaticResource TimelinesCollectionKey2}"></ParallelTimeline>
               </Storyboard.Children>
           </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger></Window.Triggers>
   ```
3. Targets:

   ```
   <Canvas>
   <Border x:Name="AnimatedBorder1" Background="Blue" Width="20" Height="20" />
   <Border x:Name="AnimatedBorder2" Background="Red" Width="20" Height="20" /></Canvas>
   ```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I do if I have a second animation, for example TopAnimation? In the first storyboard I need only one animation and in the other storyboard I need both animations. (see question)